# How to boot a system with full disk encryption from GRUB rescue

Tags: arch-linux, grub2, encryption

My system uses full disk encryption, including the boot partition. It basically follows the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system#Encrypted_boot_partition_.28GRUB.29) and uses GRUB, dm-crypt and luks. I have a single partition with both the boot and root filesystems. I specified the `cryptdevice` on the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` line of `/etc/default/grub` and added `GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y` to the file also. My system also has `/crypto_keyfile.bin` included in the `initrd` image so that I only have to enter the password once.

When booting the system, GRUB asks me for the password as I expect. If I enter the password correctly, everything boots fine. If I enter the password incorrectly, I immediately get dropped to `GRUB rescue`.

I guess I have two questions. First, is it possible to have configure grub to allow a couple of failed attempts? Second, once being dropped into `GRUB rescue`, how do I boot my system (besides using `crtl-alt-delete` like I am now)?

Answer (score 1):

Reading the documentation, you probably need, in order:

1. The [cryptomount](//www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#cryptomount) command.
2. Setting the `$root` variable to the mounted cryptofs (possibly through use of the [search](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#search) command.
3. The [normal](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#normal) command, which should load `($prefix)/grub.cfg`

After which point the boot should function as if you had entered the correct password in the first place.

Comment: Links break. Using code blocks documents solutions on SE.